# PHP：exif_read_data() not defined

Tags: php, exif

I'm now learning how to extract exif from images.I wrote the simple code like this:

```
<?php
//Get the exif data
$exif_data = exif_read_data('sample.jpg');
print_r($exif_data);
?>
```

But, there is a fatal error about undefined exif_read_data() when running the code.
I'm a windows user, and I have modified the php.ini like this :

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do these extensions show up in `phpinfo()` output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Do you have these DLLs on your system under `Php/ext` folder?
- Have you restarted Apache after editing the `php.ini`?
- The `php.ini` you edited is the one used by system? You can verify this reading `<?php phpinfo() ?>` output.
- Is there in `<?php phpinfo() ?>` output some information about the EXIF extension?

Comment: It seems, someone sees this answer to be more a comment.

Comment: I also downvoted for that reason, since when I did the answer was actually just the first bullet point at the time. That seemed more like a comment. At this point it's already more like a checklist, so the answer has improved.

Comment: Ok, in fact this is not literally an answer. I will improve it when the user will improve the question with asked infos :) Thank you.

Comment: @Oldskool: If you weren't able to undo your downvote, I've made a bump edit so you can do so.

Answer (score 3):

If you have exif.so or php_exif.dll enabled under php.ini dynamic extensions, but you still have problem running any function, it is possible that you may need to **change order of extensions in php.ini.**

In many PHP installation packages the extensions are listed alphabetically. However, exif is dependent on mbstrings to be loaded first. Yet, with alphabetic ordering the exif is listed before mbstrings and it causes the error. **Load mbstrings extensions before exif.**

Thus, do put exif as the very last extension to load and you should be fine.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.exif.php

Comment: check it using `phpinfo()`

Answer (score -2):

try this one

```
 if(extension_loaded("exif"))
    $exif_data = exif_read_data('sample.jpg','EXIF',true);
 else 
    $exif_data = false;
```