# read_exif_data & ApertureFNumber

Tags: php

I've recently come across the php function `exif_read_data` - which is pretty awesome. I'm using it on my photography site, and while it works pretty well, I'm struggling to work out why `ApertureFNumber` isn't working. The code I'm using is:

```
$exif_data = exif_read_data($image[0]);

echo $exif_data['Model'];
echo $exif_data['ExposureTime'];
echo $exif_data['FNumber'];
echo $exif_data['ApertureFNumber'];
echo $exif_data['ISOSpeedRatings'];
echo $exif_data['DateTime'];
```

(*styling removed)*

I used `FNumber` as well as `ApertureFNumber` for testing because `FNumber` works, while `ApertureFNumber`just returns blank. All the other fields work fine.

I did a var_dump of $exif_data - and this is what I get (the abridged version):

```
["ApertureFNumber"]=> string(5) "f/3.5"
["FNumber"]=> string(5) "35/10"
```

What have I missed that `FNumber` works, but `ApertureFNumber` doesn't?

--

EDIT - Complete var_dump added as requested

```
array(52) { ["FileName"]=> string(18) "MYD-67-900x602.jpg" ["FileDateTime"]=> int(0) ["FileSize"]=> int(123278) ["FileType"]=> int(2) ["MimeType"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["SectionsFound"]=> string(30) "ANY_TAG, IFD0, THUMBNAIL, EXIF" ["COMPUTED"]=> array(9) { ["html"]=> string(24) "width="900" height="602"" ["Height"]=> int(602) ["Width"]=> int(900) ["IsColor"]=> int(1) ["ByteOrderMotorola"]=> int(0) ["ApertureFNumber"]=> string(5) "f/3.5" ["FocusDistance"]=> string(14) "4294967296.00m" ["Thumbnail.FileType"]=> int(2) ["Thumbnail.MimeType"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" } ["Make"]=> string(17) "NIKON CORPORATION" ["Model"]=> string(9) "NIKON D60" ["XResolution"]=> string(5) "200/1" ["YResolution"]=> string(5) "200/1" ["ResolutionUnit"]=> int(2) ["Software"]=> string(41) "Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 4.4 (Macintosh)" ["DateTime"]=> string(19) "2013:07:06 10:07:40" ["Exif_IFD_Pointer"]=> int(216) ["THUMBNAIL"]=> array(6) { ["Compression"]=> int(6) ["XResolution"]=> string(5) "200/1" ["YResolution"]=> string(5) "200/1" ["ResolutionUnit"]=> int(2) ["JPEGInterchangeFormat"]=> int(932) ["JPEGInterchangeFormatLength"]=> int(8995) } ["ExposureTime"]=> string(5) "1/800" ["FNumber"]=> string(5) "35/10" ["ExposureProgram"]=> int(1) ["ISOSpeedRatings"]=> int(100) ["ExifVersion"]=> string(4) "0230" ["DateTimeOriginal"]=> string(19) "2008:10:30 16:04:34" ["DateTimeDigitized"]=> string(19) "2008:10:30 16:04:34" ["ShutterSpeedValue"]=> string(15) "9643856/1000000" ["ApertureValue"]=> string(13) "361471/100000" ["ExposureBiasValue"]=> string(3) "0/6" ["MaxApertureValue"]=> string(5) "36/10" ["SubjectDistance"]=> string(4) "-1/1" ["MeteringMode"]=> int(5) ["LightSource"]=> int(0) ["Flash"]=> int(0) ["FocalLength"]=> string(4) "18/1" ["SubSecTimeOriginal"]=> string(2) "50" ["SubSecTimeDigitized"]=> string(2) "50" ["SensingMethod"]=> int(2) ["FileSource"]=> string(1) "" ["SceneType"]=> string(1) "" ["CFAPattern"]=> string(8) "" ["CustomRendered"]=> int(0) ["ExposureMode"]=> int(1) ["WhiteBalance"]=> int(0) ["DigitalZoomRatio"]=> string(3) "1/1" ["FocalLengthIn35mmFilm"]=> int(27) ["SceneCaptureType"]=> int(0) ["GainControl"]=> int(0) ["Contrast"]=> int(0) ["Saturation"]=> int(0) ["Sharpness"]=> int(0) ["SubjectDistanceRange"]=> int(0) ["UndefinedTag:0xA431"]=> string(7) "6265825" ["UndefinedTag:0xA432"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(4) "18/1" [1]=> string(4) "55/1" [2]=> string(5) "35/10" [3]=> string(5) "56/10" } ["UndefinedTag:0xA434"]=> string(22) "18.0-55.0 mm f/3.5-5.6" }
```

Comment: Similar problem here check dis 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573070/phpexif-read-data-not-defined

Comment: var_dump($exif_data); and sow the complete dump here

Comment: var_dump added. I checked that other stackoverflow post - EXIF 1.4 is enabled on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got this figured out now - and thought you might like to see the answer.

The var_dump was giving the data `["ApertureFNumber"]=> string(5) "f/3.5"`, but wasn't really getting me anywhere, so instead I used `print_r($exif_data)`. That printed out a whole load of useful data including the following:

```
[COMPUTED] => Array
        (
            [html] => width="1000" height="667"
            [Height] => 667
            [Width] => 1000
            [IsColor] => 1
            [ByteOrderMotorola] => 0
            [ApertureFNumber] => f/3.5
            [Thumbnail.FileType] => 2
            [Thumbnail.MimeType] => image/jpeg
            [Thumbnail.Height] => 171
            [Thumbnail.Width] => 256
        )
```

So, to echo out the needed `ApertureFNumber` I simply used 
`echo $exif['COMPUTED']['ApertureFNumber'];` It also works for any of the information in the printed array.

Hopefully this helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
$exif = exif_read_data($image[0]);
foreach($exif as $exif_data){
echo $exif_data['Model']."<br/>";
echo $exif_data['ExposureTime']."<br/>";
echo $exif_data['FNumber']."<br/>";
echo "ApertureFNumber is:" .$exif_data['ApertureFNumber']."<br/>";
echo $exif_data['ISOSpeedRatings']."<br/>";
echo $exif_data['DateTime']."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: That echos `MMMMMMiiiiiiAAAAAAf/3.5NNNNNNNNNNNN222222222222AAAAAA222222111111333333000000222222222222999999333333000000333333------111111555555555555111111666666111111`

The f/3.5 is in there though - so it's a step closer!

Comment: I have highlighted the `ApertureFNumber` check it

Comment: Well that puts a line break in between each one, but it still spews out a lot of gobbledegook...

Comment: print this in your loop `echo "ApertureFNumber is:" .$exif_data['ApertureFNumber'];` and remove every thing

Comment: Returns:
**ApertureFNumber is:**
And nothing else